# Add a column for the filename while batch loading many files in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

What would be the best way, with shp2pgsql, to add a column containing the name of the source file while loading many shapefiles in PostGIS?

raster2pgsql has a -F option for that.

Comment: IMO there is a difference (problem) between the both tools  shp2pgsql and  raster2pgsql. shp2pgsql produces a set of rows with attribute and geo-data, while raster2pgsql produces one line with data related  to the import file. Would you like to repeat the file name for each shape record?

Comment: If you tile the raster with the -t option, raster2pgsql will produce many lines per imported raster like shp2pgsql import many lines per shapefile. I would not mind repeating the filename for every row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hack that abuses the `application_name` variable:

1. Create the table that the contents of all shapefiles will be added to.
2. Run `ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN filename text DEFAULT current_setting('application_name');`
3. Override the application name when loading via `shp2pgsql`, e.g.:

   `shp2pgsql -a ne_110m_ocean.shp my_table | PGAPPNAME="ne_110m_ocean.shp" psql`
4. Run `ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN filename DROP DEFAULT;`